# Check if command is in certain channel

Tags: discord, discord.js, bots

I have a script that checks if a user has a certain role to see if they can use a certain command. Those role ids are stored in a json file like so:

```
[ "roleid1", "roleid2", "roleid3" ]
```

i would like to use the same concept to store the channel ids, but cannot figure out how. this is the code for my role checking:

```js
delete require.cache[require.resolve("./resources/lookup_perms.json")];
const roles = require("./resources/lookup_perms.json");
const result = msg.member.roles.cache.some(r => roles.includes(r.id));
    
Actions.storeValue(result, 1, "auth", cache);
Actions.callNextAction(cache)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check the message channel id

```js
if (msg.channel.id === "CHANNEL_ID_HERE") {
    // Code here
}
```

Replace CHANNEL_ID_HERE with the channel id you want

Edit:
If you want to check an array of channels you can use .includes like this:

```js
if (["ChannelId1", "ChannelId2"].includes(msg.channel.id))
{
    // Code here
}
```

Comment: Thanks, how can I do this with an array of channels though?

Answer (score 1):

Not really sure how you are doing all of that as you are not showing all of your code, but **BY ASSUMING**. I guess you are trying to figure out how to check the channels?

Just like you did with your roles:

```js
const result = msg.member.roles.cache.some(r => roles.includes(r.id));
```

You can just do the same with channels

```js
const result = msg.guild.channels.cache.some(ch => ch.includes(ch.id));
```